# Is this async/await function writing to mongo collection before page redirect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

I have a route in express with a function that adds some req.body attributes info to a mongo collection. It works, but I’m not happy with it, it feels wrong to me, and I don’t think I’ve got my head around async/await yet.

This is the code:

```
router.post("/input/:id", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  Project.findOne({
_id: req.params.id
  }).then(project => {
const newInput = {
  inputTitle: req.body.inputTitle,
  inputValue: req.body.inputValue,
  inputUnits: req.body.inputUnits,
  inputCategory: req.body.inputCategory,
  inputUser: req.user.id
};
// Add to the array, this is the async function
(async () => {
  await project.inputs.unshift(newInput);
})();
project.save().then(project => {
  res.redirect(`/projects/output/${project.id}`);
  });
 });
});
```

Is that async function doing what I think/hope it’s doing (I want it to add the newInput variable to the database before the page redirects)? What's the best way of doing this? Should I try and write it all as one function?

Comment: *Should I try and write it all as one function* - yes. async IIFE and raw promises inside another async don't make sense. *I don’t think I’ve got my head around async/await yet.* - you can write it with ES6 alone if you feel more confident with raw promises.

Comment: I figured that it wasn't too neat, but I really just need to make sure that it writes to mongo before it redirects. I tried it without the async/await (using the .then), but someone testing it complained that it wasn't writing to the db.

Comment: On second thought, I guess it likely writes before. I didn't read the code properly because of indentation. Also `await project.inputs.unshift(newInput);` isn't needed. It isn't a promise and it doesn't have to be awaited. It may cause race condition here.